# CMU Sphinx4 phoneme dictation

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, jsapi, phoneme

How can I configure sphinx4 to be able to detect only phonemes in a dictation?

I've already read about [partial results](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/Sphinx4-faq.html#partial_results)

"You can control how often the result listener is fired by setting the configuration variable 'featureBlockSize' in the decoder."

But my problem is that there are always a grammar needed, like hello.gram in the helloworld example. I need to be able to detect and recognize phoneme from a continuous speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Sphinx has to say about it:

[Phoneme Recognition](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/phonemerecognition)

Basically, You can do it but it is looked down upon.

Answer (score 1):

You can not configure sphinx4 this way. This decoding mode is not supported by sphinx4 yet.