# Decode speech into Phonemes in Sphinx4

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4, phoneme

Can I use CMUSphinx4 to decode a particular speech into phonemes and get those phonemes into further implementations?

Comment: No, it's not supported. An exact duplicate question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048163/cmu-sphinx4-phoneme-dictation

Comment: Then could you please tell me how the sphinx4 recognize the speech (the methodology).

Comment: Sure, you can check the tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialconcepts Speech recognizers do not look for phonemes, because phonemes pronuncation depends on context. Instead, speech recognizers look for words as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using sphinx4 (beta 6), there is a method within the framework called **getBestPronunciationResult()**

> "The method is used when the application wants the phonemes on the
>   best final path. Note that words may have more than one pronunciation,
>   so this is not equivalent to the word path e.g. one[HH,W,AH,N]
>   to[T,UW] three[TH,R,IY]
>
> Returns:
>       the String of words and associated phonemes on the best path"

Location: src/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/result/Result.java

Token.java is the class which does the actual work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Found this sample code that would take in a recognition result object and dump the phonemes 
:http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/sphinx4:unittimestamps

I found this paper to be very useful in understanding Sphinx4 : http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/Sphinx4Whitepaper.pdf

Once I understood the architecture, I went through the list of packages found on the javadoc page.

Hope that helps. Good luck !

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.